# Best free auto updater c#

Tags: c#, .net

what is best free auto update tool for .net desktop applications currently(for this date)? I use ".NET Application Updater Component", but it's made in 2002. 
---NOT ClickOnce (it has many limitations )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one http://autoupdater.codeplex.com/